# Apply Same logic in multiple columns - Multi Processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, subprocess

I am new to python and I have requirement to handle columns like below

Source Data:

```
John|100|john@gmail.com|London
Harvey|200|Harvey@gmail.com|Cork
```

I am performing the same operation on column 3rd and 4th ( This would vary). In this case, I am replacing 'o' with some 'Z'

Output Data :

```
John|100|jZhn@gmail.com|LZndZn
Harvey|200|Harvey@gmail.cZm|CZrk
```

So I have tried

```
noofattributes=[3,4]
actual1= 'o'
replace1 = 'Z'
with open('newinfile.txt') as inf, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outf:


   for line in inf:
      items = line.strip().split('|')

      for column in noofattributes:
           items[column] = items[column].translate(str.maketrans( actual1, replace1))

      toBeWritten.append('|'.join(items))
      outf.writelines(toBeWritten)
      outf.writelines("\n")
```

The above code is working fine. But It is sequential processing. I am looking for a method to run in parallel i.e., Column 3 and 4 processed at the same time and results are merged at the end. Please help me this.

The file which I am processing is of 100 GB and columns which needs to be modified go from 10 to 20. The current code is slower.

Comment: Attempting to parallelize this seems completely misdirected. The overhead of copying the data between memory locations and reassembling the columns into well-formed lines will completely dominate over any gains from multiprocessing (which are highly doubtful in this scenario anyway; character substitutions are a simple and efficient operation).

Comment: Split the file into e.g. 1GB chunks (preserving whole lines) and run those in parallel instead. Disk I/O also parallelizes poorly so maybe only do approximately 10 files at a time.